# Return the DOM elements via a CSS selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have these lines of HTML:

```
<div id="ID1" class="Class1 Class3"></div>
<p id="ID2" class="Class2 Class3"></p>
```

I want to be able to return the HTML elements in an array given a CSS selector or TagName, this is what I have so far:

```js
const selectors = document.getElementsByClassName("Class3");

let arr = [];
while (selectors) {
  arr.push(selectors);
  selectors = selectors.parentNode;
}

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="ID1" class="Class1 Class3"></div>
<p id="ID2" class="Class2 Class3"></p>
```

This code works and returns the HTML elements, but how do I alter the code so it just returns the HTML elements (div and p), rather than the HTML elements as well as CSS selectors - if possible?

So that the output is: `[div, p]`

***EDIT***
I can't use `document.querySelector`/`document.querySelectorAll` or any libraries`

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: not that is matters to this question, but your example HTML is invalid. id's must be unique.

Comment: `document.querySelector("p.Class3")`

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("div")

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is part of the DOM; it is not part of a "library". But perhaps you need to explain more about your homework assignment...

Comment: Your question is unclear due to your repeated use of the term "DOM Element". `selectors` is already an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of DOM Elements which acts like an array. You should be able to simply use selectors and pull out the object properties you need.  Please clarify **EXACTLY** what you want as an output by providing a sample output given your sample input.

Comment: @RandyCasburn updated

Comment: thanks! then all you need to do is `for(let selector of selectors){ arr.push(selector.nodeName);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do a `for of` and clone the element for attribute removal. Like this...

```js
const selectors = document.getElementsByClassName("Class3");
const arr = [];
for (let selector of selectors) {
  const element = selector.cloneNode();
  for (let i = element.attributes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    element.removeAttribute(element.attributes[i].name);
  }
  arr.push(element);
}
console.log(selectors, arr);
```

**Note that the inverse traverse order matters**

The output

[image]

Hope it helps.

**Protip:** use `const` and `let` for vars now. Actually, "**let** is the new **var**".

Comment: Your answer is closest - please see the OP's edited question and change your answer to reflect that change and you've got it.

Comment: You could clone the element and copy the contents only before adding it in the array.

Comment: If it does what you want, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the HTMLCollection that is returned by `document.getElementsByClassName` using a simple `for` loop. 
Then using the index of each element then you can easily access the element.
You can either use `nodeName` or  `localName` property of the element object to get their tags.

```js
var s = document.getElementsByClassName("Class3");

let arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= s.length-1; i++){
 arr.push(s[i].localName)
}
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div id="ID2" class="Class1 Class3"></div>
<p id="ID2" class="Class2 Class3"></p>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks man! But I can't use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @dumbquestionsbydumbpeople check now, updated as per your needs

Comment: Answers which explain code changes are upvoted more often than those which simply show code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use this JavaScript code

```
var s = document.querySelectorAll(".Class3");

var arr = [];
s.forEach((e, key) => {
    arr.push(e.nodeName)
})
 console.log(arr);
```